# Flutter: Handling Asynchronous Operation

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an asynchronous function that uploads files to firebase storage. I am trying to return the download url retrieved for each file through a list of string. However, the problem I am having is that the function execute the `return` line before the asynchronous operation is done.

My code looks like this:

```dart
Future<List<String>> uploadAssets() async {
    List<String> downloadUrls = List<String>();
    if (assets.isNotEmpty && !textOnly) {
      assets.forEach((asset) async {
        if (asset.runtimeType == Asset) {
          ByteData byteData = await asset.requestOriginal(quality: 85);
          List<int> assetData = byteData.buffer.asUint8List();
          StorageUploadTask uploadTask = storageRef
            .child('post_${Uuid().v4()}.jpg')
            .putData(assetData);
          StorageTaskSnapshot storageSnap = await uploadTask.onComplete;
          String downloadUrl = await storageSnap.ref.getDownloadURL();
          downloadUrls.add(downloadUrl);
        }
      });
    }
    return downloadUrls;
  }
```

I expect the function to return a list of string with download urls retrieved from firebase but instead it returns an empty list. How do I approach this?

Comment: it looks like one of the functions you call is not doing what you expect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid the use of `forEach`. In this case, you are creating closures that will each finish after the `forEach` loop.

Instead, use a normal `for` loop, so that each will complete in turn.

```
if (assets.isNotEmpty && !textOnly) {
  for (var asset in assets) {
    if (asset.runtimeType == Asset) {
      ByteData byteData = await asset.requestOriginal(quality: 85);
      List<int> assetData = byteData.buffer.asUint8List();
      StorageUploadTask uploadTask = storageRef
        .child('post_${Uuid().v4()}.jpg')
        .putData(assetData);
      StorageTaskSnapshot storageSnap = await uploadTask.onComplete;
      String downloadUrl = await storageSnap.ref.getDownloadURL();
      downloadUrls.add(downloadUrl);
    }
  }
}
```

If you really want to have the uploads complete in parallel, look into `Future.wait` where you could kick them all off and then wait for all the futures to complete.

Comment: Thank you bro for the explanation. About the ```Future.wait```, please can you give an example for this case. If not, no problem, the ```for``` loop is enough. I just want to try and see which one is better in terms of performance. I will look into it and see if i will be able to apply it

Comment: Search "dartlang wait more than one future" for the best existing answer.